# Python Selenium find table and click in the first row

Tags: python, selenium

I am struggling with this so I hope someone can help me out.

The Website generates dynamically tables which I need to interact with. With this Code:

```
def find_table(browser:object, th:int, header:str, select_first=False, double_click_first=False):

    for index, head in enumerate(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//th[{th}]")):
        print(head.text)
        if head.text == header: break
    
    print(index)
    
    tables = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table")
    print(len(tables))
    
    main_table = tables[index]
    test = main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//tr[1]/td[3]").text
    print(test)
    
    if select_first == True:
        main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, f".//tr[1]/td[{th}]").click()

    if double_click_first == True:
        first_row = main_table.find_element(By.XPATH, f".//tr[1]/td[{th}]")
        action = ActionChains(browser)
        action.double_click(first_row).perform()
```

For the first table

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/form[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]
```

everything work as I expect, but for the next table

```
/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[17]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]
```

I got an Exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//tr[1]/td[3]"}

The weird part for me is that the prints shows all correctly. Correct Header Text, correct Index, correct total of tables.

Comment: What's the url, is it publicly available?

Comment: Sadly not, since it is used only company internally

Comment: Can you post page' html somewhere like pastebin then? Those xpaths look terribly fragile and un-proper, to say the least.